# How can I send a body message with mpack?

Tags: linux, shell, email

How can I send a body message with `mpack`?

```
mpack -s "Test" /home/Desktop/text.txt example@exampledomain.com
```

In this scenario, it will sent a `text.txt` file with the subject ''test'', but what if I want to send a message body with it.

I tried:

```
echo "Body Message" | mpack -s "Subject" file.txt myemail@test.com
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Include it as a description.

Example:

```
echo "this is the message body" > message_body.txt
mpack -s "Subject goes here.." -d message_body.txt email@example.com
rm message_body.txt
```